# Angular Prerender chart.js

Tags: angular, chart.js, angular-universal

I'm having a problem with angular prerendering with chart.js (v3.9.1)

The code runs fine and compiles in build, but with **npm run prerender**, I get the following error.

> ./src/app/shared/charts/chartjs/chartjs.component.ts:16:27-32 - Error:
> export 'default' (imported as 'Chart') was not found in
> 'chart.js/auto' (possible exports: Animation, Animations, ArcElement,
> BarController, BarElement, BasePlatform, BasicPlatform,
> BubbleController, CategoryScale, Chart, DatasetController, Decimation,
> DomPlatform, DoughnutController, Element, Filler, Interaction, Legend,
> LineController, LineElement, LinearScale, LogarithmicScale,
> PieController, PointElement, PolarAreaController, RadarController,
> RadialLinearScale, Scale, ScatterController, SubTitle, Ticks,
> TimeScale, TimeSeriesScale, Title, Tooltip, __esModule, _adapters,
> _detectPlatform, animator, controllers, defaults, elements, layouts, plugins, registerables, registry, scales)

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import Chart from 'chart.js/auto';
import { ChartConfiguration } from 'chart.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-chartjs',
  templateUrl: './chartjs.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chartjs.component.scss']
})
export class ChartjsComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('myChart') myCanvas!: ElementRef<HTMLCanvasElement>;

  @Input() config:ChartConfiguration; 

  myChart:Chart;
  //linear:LinearScale;
  //nut:DoughnutController;

  constructor() {
    //Chart.register(...registerables);
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.myChart = new Chart(this.myCanvas.nativeElement, this.config);

  }

}
```

Comment: what's behind your `prerender` script ?

Comment: Not sure I follow exactly, I'm just running the defaults that come out of the box. I configured the prerender options in angular.json to use only a specific route.